# Difficult sort order with Linq to SQL

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I have a List of objects that I need sorted a particular way.

The relevant table fields are:

- ID (int)
- IsMandatory (bit)
- ParentID (int nullable)
- Code (varchar)

I need them sorted by IsMandatory=true first, then by Code, but anything with a ParentID must be sorted by Code but appear straight after the row with the same ID as ParentID (and these records will always have IsMandatory set to NULL).

Some sample data, and this is also in the order in which they should appear when ordered:

- ID=1, IsMandatory=1, ParentID=NULL, Code="A"
- ID=2, IsMandatory=NULL, ParentID=1, Code="A"
- ID=3, IsMandatory=NULL, ParentID=1, Code="B"
- ID=4, IsMandatory=1, ParentID=NULL, Code="B"
- ID=5, IsMandatory=0, ParentID=NULL, Code="C"
- ID=6, IsMandatory=NULL, ParentID=5, Code="A"
- ID=7, IsMandatory=0, ParentID=NULL, Code="D"

How would this best be accomplished in a Linq to SQL orderby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a difficult sort!

The reason for the difficulty stems from the fact you are ordering on the Parents record properties first and then the actual records properties.

I tried to make the variables as self explanatory as possible, but if you have any questions please ask!

```
  var query = from x in context.Table
              let parent = list.FirstOrDefault(y => x.ParentID == y.ID)
              let parentIsMandatory = parent == null ? x.IsMandatory : parent.IsMandatory
              let parentIsMandatoryOrder = parentIsMandatory == true ? 0 : 1
              let parentCode = parent == null ? x.Code : parent.Code
              let parentId = x.ParentID ?? x.ID
              let isParent = x.ParentID == null ? 0 : 1
              orderby parentIsMandatoryOrder, parentCode, parentId, isParent, x.Code
              select x;
```